# Selenium WebDriver issue

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I am getting:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from FirefoxDriver to WebDriver" error in the console

I have added jars files correctly..but still facing issue..please help [image]

```
package demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestFacebookRegistration {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to post your code, please.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I meant post the code, NOT a screenshot of it 

Comment: Also, look at your imports;  they are not resolving.  Do you have the proper references in your project?

Comment: sorry...updated

Comment: But when I try to resolve the errors with imports it shows like " Package org.openqa.selenium.firefox is accessible from more than one moduleclient.cmbined,okio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using FirefoxDriver, you now have to use Geckodriver's

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();    
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/how-to-use-geckodriver/)

Comment: but I have already set the system properties for Geckodriver in the system settings

Comment: Can you please share the full code. Also like Brian mentioned you have code import resolve issues. Is it resolved now?

Comment: No.when I try to resolve the errors with imports, it shows like " Package org.openqa.selenium.firefox is accessible from more than one moduleclient.cmbined,okio in the popup when mouse hovering above the import statements

Comment: Can you check this link, exact same issue you are mentioning. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834695/the-package-org-openqa-selenium-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue in your package, I think you missed one of them. I suggest you to use the pom so that it install all of thel automatically. By the way, the webdriver for Firefoix is geckodriver, not marionnette.